# What does a triangle instead of a circle / dot mean at a junction in a schematic?

Tags: schematics, datasheet

Looking at a datasheet, there is a schematic with a triangle over some of the junction points between wires instead of the normal filled circle. What does this mean?
The datasheet is [this one](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/UG-419.pdf) for an Analog Devices Eval Board for an AD7328 ADC.

What does a triangle instead of a circle / dot mean at a junction in a schematic?

[image: example of the triangle]

Comment: Mistaken symbols are all over that document in the final circuit

Comment: I'd guess this is just some graphical error that has happened when exporting the schematic from whatever CAD software they've drawn it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is just a conversion error when they converted the schematic to a pdf format. I assume it would mean the same thing as a dot (and was probably a dot in their schematics), but the only way to know for sure is to contact analog and ask them what they mean and/or to correct their error.

Comment: thanks, yeah that makes sense. Just wasn't sure if it was something about the separation of analog ground vs digital ground or some such.